# How to find matching values of two ranges and edit the cell next to the common values?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I hire out cameras to film students within a university. To keep track of what I have in stock and which students have a camera, I have created a [google sheet.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CYv8n.jpg)

The extended version of this example includes over a hundred cameras, so to make my life easier, I'd like to enter into the BASKET the name of the cameras being hired, then type the name of the student hiring it out into the NAME cell.

Students may hire out more than one camera at a time, and so, upon clicking the 'Check Out' button which in turn triggers the function 'checkOut', I would like to change the cell next to the cameras referenced from 'Available' to the students name.

I'm new to Google Apps Script but I know the first step to this is listing each variable needed, then find the basket values within the Equipment List and replace the offset cell with the Name value.

Here are my variables:

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var basket = ss.getRange("A2:A");
var name = ss.getRange("C2");
var equipmentlist = ss.getRange("E2:E11");

function checkOut() {

}
```

I hope all this makes sense. I have not been able to find anything online about finding matching values of two different ranges and changing the cell next to those values.

Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
function checkOut() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var name = sh.getRange("C2").getValue();
  if(name && name.length>0 && getColumnHeight(1)>1) {
    var basketrg = sh.getRange(2,1,getColumnHeight(1)-1,1);
    var basket = basketrg.getValues();
    var equipmentlist = sh.getRange(2,5,getColumnHeight(5)-1,1).getValues();
    var availabilitylist = sh.getRange(2,6,getColumnHeight(6)-1,1).getValues();
    for(var i=0;i<equipmentlist.length;i++) {
      for(var j=0;j<basket.length;j++) {
        if(equipmentlist[i][0]==basket[j][0]){
          availabilitylist[i][0]=name;
        }
      }
    }
    sh.getRange(2,6,availabilitylist.length,1).setValues(availabilitylist);
    setCameraList();
    basketrg.clearContent();
    sh.getRange('C2').clearContent()
  }else{
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert('Invalid Input: No name provided or no cameras selected in checkOut() function.');
  }
}

function getColumnHeight(col,sh,ss){
  var ss=ss || SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=sh || ss.getActiveSheet();
  var col=col || sh.getActiveCell().getColumn();
  var rg=sh.getRange(1,col,sh.getLastRow(),1);
  var vA=rg.getValues();
  while(vA[vA.length-1][0].length==0){
    vA.splice(vA.length-1,1);
  }
  return vA.length;
}
```

## A Simple CheckOut System

To setup this system you will want to copy all of the scripts bellow into the Code.gs file in the script editor of a Spreadsheet. Name your sheet 'CheckOut'. You will also want to created a named range named "AvailableCameras" and the range will be 'CheckOut!K2:K1000' and a Data Validation for 'CheckOut!A2:A20' or however large you want your basket to be.

You can add as many cameras as you wish (well within reason... the more you add the slower it runs).  As you checkout cameras the list of camera choices in your basket gets smaller.   When cameras are returned you can clear out the names from the available list and the system will add the available label back for you and it will also increase the number of available cameras.

This is what the Spreadsheet looks like:

[image]

Code.gs:

```
function onOpen() {
  makeMenu();
}

function makeMenu(){
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu('My Tools')
  .addItem('Check Out', 'checkOut')
  .addItem('Set Camera List', 'setCameraList')
  .addItem('Set Available List', 'setAvailableList')
  .addToUi();
}

function checkOut() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var name = sh.getRange("C2").getValue();
  if(name && name.length>0) {
    var basketrg = sh.getRange(2,1,getColumnHeight(1)-1,1);
    var basket = basketrg.getValues();
    var equipmentlist = sh.getRange(2,5,getColumnHeight(5)-1,1).getValues();
    var availabilitylist = sh.getRange(2,6,getColumnHeight(6)-1,1).getValues();
    for(var i=0;i<equipmentlist.length;i++) {
      for(var j=0;j<basket.length;j++) {
        if(equipmentlist[i][0]==basket[j][0]){
          availabilitylist[i][0]=name;
        }
      }
    }
    sh.getRange(2,6,availabilitylist.length,1).setValues(availabilitylist);
    setCameraList();
    basketrg.clearContent();
    sh.getRange('C2').clearContent()
  }else{
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert('Invalid Input: No name provided in checkOut() function.');
  }
}

function setCameraList() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName('CheckOut');
  var LISTrg=ss.getRangeByName('AvailableCameras');
  var rg=sh.getRange(2,5,getColumnHeight(5)-1,2);
  var vA=rg.getValues();
  LISTrg.clear();
  var listA=[];
  for(var i=0;i<vA.length;i++) {
    if(vA[i][1]=='Available') {
      listA.push([vA[i][0]]);
    }
  }
  sh.getRange(2,11,listA.length,1).setValues(listA);
}

function onEdit(e) {
  var rg=e.range;
  var sh=rg.getSheet();
  var name=sh.getName();
  if(name!='CheckOut'){return;}
  if(rg.columnStart==1 && rg.rowStart>1) {
     setCameraList();
  }  
  if(rg.columnStart==6 && rg.rowStart>1) {
    setAvailableList();
    setCameraList();
  }
}

function setAvailableList() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName('CheckOut');
  var rg=sh.getRange(2,6,getColumnHeight(5)-1,1);
  var vA=rg.getValues();
  for(var i=0;i<vA.length;i++) {
    if(!vA[i][0] && vA[i][0].length==0) {
      vA[i][0]='Available';
    }
  }
  rg.setValues(vA);
}

function getColumnHeight(col,sh,ss){
  var ss=ss || SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=sh || ss.getActiveSheet();
  var col=col || sh.getActiveCell().getColumn();
  var rg=sh.getRange(1,col,sh.getLastRow(),1);
  var vA=rg.getValues();
  while(vA[vA.length-1][0].length==0){
    vA.splice(vA.length-1,1);
  }
  return vA.length;
}
```

Comment: You sir, are a genius. Thank you so much!

Comment: I played around with this and I have a fairly useful working version of a checkout system.  Would you like to have it?

Comment: Yes please, I'd love to take a look

Comment: I'll add it to my answer.

Comment: I modified the `checkOut()` function to provide an alert when you try to checkout with no name provided or no cameras selected.

Comment: This looks brilliant, great idea. I'll try and expand on this with maybe a checkIn() and a clearBasket() function. Should be pretty simple using what you've written.

Comment: Another quick question; should I want to store my equipment list on another worksheet within the document (for when I have a very long list) how would I import that range? I am trying to use the following: var equipmentlist = ss.getSheetByName('Equipment Tracking').getRange(2,2,getColumnHeight(2)-1,1).getValues();

Comment: If you have a very long list of equipment then I probably wouldn't do it this way.  I'd use a webapp instead.  I try to avoid using server triggers on complex problems because I don't like to consume a lot of server bandwidth.  Also  I find that complex use of onEdit can lead one down a path of creating subtle race conditions that are difficult to solve.